# Есть ли ещё такие, как глагол "расследует"? ( О двувидовых глаголах)

Tags: глаголы

Глагол "расследует" (или "исследует") в настоящем и будущем времени пишется одинаково. Есть ли ещё такие глаголы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, речь идет не о настоящем-будущем времени, а о так называемых ***двувидовых глаголах***, имеющих общую форму для совершенного и несовершенного вида, т.е. отвечающих одновременно на вопросы *«что делать?»* и *«что сделать?»* (что и порождает единые форы для «что делает?» и «что сделает?», а также для «что делал?» и «что сделал?»).

Таких глаголов в русском — вагон и маленькая тележка. Например, это все глаголы на «-ировать»: *позиционировать, ассистировать, кремировать...*
Кроме того, к ним относится большинство глаголов церковнославянского происхождения.

Из остальных: *венчать, женить, крестить, бежать* (в значении «срочно или тайно покидать место пребывания  или события»), *комиссовать, стяжать, судить...*

Больше здесь: [**Двувидовые глаголы** | ru.wiktionary.org](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%94%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B).

Там присутствует несколько глаголов, принадлежность которых к двувидовым можно подвергнуть сомнению («царствовать», например), но в целом список очень показательный.

Answer (score 5):

ИССЛЕДОВАТЬ,  **св. и нсв**. 1. что. Подвергнуть - подвергать научному рассмотрению

Существуют **двувидовые глаголы**, когда одна форма может выражать значения как совершенного, так и несовершенного вида, например: атаковать, ранить, обещать, велеть.  Значение того или другого вида выявляется в контексте.

**Категории времени и вида глагола  связаны между собой.**  Глаголы несовершенного вида имеют три формы времени: думает, думал, будет думать (будущее сложное). Глаголы совершенного вида имеют только две формы времени: подумал и подумает (будущее простое).

Для глагола "исследовать": несов. вид: **исследует (сейчас),** исследовал, будет исследовать; сов. вид: исследовал и **исследует (в будущем).**